# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ order_graph_1: any; order_graph_2: any; }'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-props

```
interface MyProps {
    order_graph_1: any;
    order_graph_2: any;setOrder: any}

class Setup extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState>{
    orders: { order_graph_1: any; order_graph_2: any; };
    constructor(props: MyProps){
        super(props);
        this.orders = {
            "order_graph_1":this.props.order_graph_1,
            "order_graph_2":this.props.order_graph_2
        }; 
    }
    
    setOrders(event: { target: { name: React.ReactText; value: string; }; }){
        this.orders[event.target.name] = parseInt(event.target.value);
    }
```

I am trying to change a JS code into TS and I get this error on:

```
this.orders[event.target.name]
```

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'ReactText' can't be used to index type '{ order_graph_1: any; order_graph_2: any; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ order_graph_1: any; order_graph_2: any; }'.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are confident that the name is one of the keys then you can assert its type: `this.orders[event.target.name as keyof MyProps]`

Comment: MyProps also has another property so this would give me an error ```Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"order_graph_1" | "order_graph_2" | "setOrders"' can't be used to index type '{ order_graph_1: any; order_graph_2: any; }'.
  Property 'setOrders' does not exist on type '{ order_graph_1: any; order_graph_2: any; }'``` @LindaPaiste

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that because it's on the same line.  You can assert the correctness lots of ways: `this.orders[event.target.name as 'order_graph_1' | 'order_graph_2']` .  But I've just realized that `this.orders` is not part of `state`!  This is bad design.  It needs to be in your state. (All of those `any` annotations are bad too).  I will write an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'll fix the types, but gotta get it running first :P Thanks! @LindaPaiste

Comment: What is the purpose of the `setOrder` prop?  Does this component update the state in a parent?  I'm not sure if it needs to store the orders at all or if it is supposed to just send and receive data from a parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript does not know that the `string` from `event.target.name` is a valid key of `this.orders`.  You need to assert that the `name` matches your acceptable values with `as`.

This is a common enough problem that I was going to redirect you to another answer but there are some other red flags in this code that I want to address.

**You are storing stateful data outside of state**.  Don't do this!  Your component will not re-render at the right times with the right values.  The `orders` should be part of `this.state`, either here or in a parent.  I am not sure why you are passing down values from props when you are updating them here which leads me to wonder if maybe this component should have no state and should just use a callback to set state in a parent.  React recommends that you should not create your state based on props [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) and [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html).  But I'll ignore that for now and assume that these are initial values.

**Ditch the `any`**.  You lose the benefits of typescript when you use `any` as a type. The value in your `setOrders` comes from `parseInt`, so we know that `order_graph_1` and `order_graph_2` should be type `number`.  Why not say that?

Code:

```
import React from "react";

interface Orders {
  order_graph_1: number;
  order_graph_2: number;
}

interface MyProps extends Orders {
  setOrder: (...args: any) => void; // function which takes args...??
}

interface MyState extends Orders {
  otherProperty: string;
}

class Setup extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  // don't need a constructor just to set state
  state = {
    // it is best not to derive state from props
    order_graph_1: this.props.order_graph_1,
    order_graph_2: this.props.order_graph_2,
    // just to show that we can have other properties alongside the orders
    otherProperty: ""
  };

  // needs to be an arrow function to access `this` properly
  // could use ( event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
  // could avoid the assertion by passing the name as an argument
  setOrders = (event: { target: { name: React.ReactText; value: string } }) => {
    // I don't love this solution, but we can avoid the TS errors by copying the previous state
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value)
    }));
  };

  // helper function avoids having to duplicate info for the two inputs
  // can set any of these atrributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number
  // or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes
  renderInput = (name: keyof Orders) => (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={name}>{name}</label>
      <input
        id={name} // label htmlFor matches id
        name={name}
        value={this.state[name]}
        onChange={this.setOrders}
        type="number"
        min={0} // don't allow negatives
        step={1} // allow whole numbers only
      />
    </>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderInput("order_graph_1")}
        {this.renderInput("order_graph_2")}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697152/unable-to-type-in-react-input-field