# unable to type in react input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-props

Currently, the default value of my input field is 1. If I try to type something in the input field, nothing changes.

```
interface Orders {
    order_graph_1: number;
    order_graph_2: number;
  }

  interface MyProps extends Orders {
    setOrders: (...args: any) => void; // function which takes args...??
  }

  interface MyState extends Orders {
    //otherProperty: string;
  }
  
      

class Setup extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState>{
    state = {
        order_graph_1: this.props.order_graph_1,
        order_graph_2: this.props.order_graph_2
      };
    
      // needs to be an arrow function to access `this` properly
      // could use ( event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
      // could avoid the assertion by passing the name as an argument
      setOrders = (event: any) => {

        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          [event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value)
        }));
      };
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                    <p className="text-center">Order of first model: </p>
                    <div className="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <input className="text-center" name="order_graph_1" type="number" value={this.props.order_graph_1} onChange={this.setOrders.bind(this)} min="1" max="10"/>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Setup;
```

To test, I canged the onChange function

```
onChange={()=>console.log("hello")}
```

everytime I tried to type in the input field, I saw hello being printed in the console but the value of the input field still does not change.

edit:

This was a JS code (https://github.com/MenesesGHZ/polynomial-regression-js):

```
class RegressionSetup extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.orders = {
            "order_graph_1":this.props.order_graph_1,
            "order_graph_2":this.props.order_graph_2
        }; 
    }
    
    setOrders(event){
        this.orders[event.target.name] = parseInt(event.target.value);
        this.props.setOrders(Object.values(this.orders));
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                    <p className="text-center">Order of first model: </p>
                    <div className="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <input className="text-center" name="order_graph_1" type="number" value={this.props.order_graph_1} onChange={this.setOrders.bind(this)} min="1" max="10"/>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-6">
                    <p className="text-center">Order of second model: </p>
                    <div className="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <input className="text-center"name="order_graph_2" type="number" value={this.props.order_graph_2} onChange={this.setOrders.bind(this)} min="1" max="10"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RegressionSetup;
```

Upon changing the value of input, a line on a graph changed according to the value. I had to change this code to Typescript. This is what I have now.

```
interface Orders {
    order_graph_1: number;
    order_graph_2: number;
  }

  interface MyProps extends Orders {
    setOrders: (...args: any) => void; // function which takes args...??
  }

  interface MyState extends Orders {
    //otherProperty: string;
  }
  
      

class Setup extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState>{
    state = {
        // it is best not to derive state from props
        order_graph_1: this.props.order_graph_1,
        order_graph_2: this.props.order_graph_2
      };
    
      // needs to be an arrow function to access `this` properly
      // could use ( event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
      // could avoid the assertion by passing the name as an argument
      setOrders = (event: any) => {
        // I don't love this solution, but we can avoid the TS errors by copying the previous state
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          [event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value)
        }));
      };
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                    <p className="text-center">Order of first model: </p>
                    <div className="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <input className="text-center" name="order_graph_1" type="number" value={this.state.order_graph_1} onChange={this.setOrders.bind(this)} min="1" max="10"/>
                </div>
                </div>
                {/* <div className="col-6">
                    <p className="text-center">Order of second model: </p>
                    <div className="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <input className="text-center"name="order_graph_2" type="number" value={this.props.order_graph_2} onChange={this.setOrders.bind(this)} min="1" max="10"/>
                    </div>
                </div> */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Setup;
```

although it compiles without an error, the input value thing is not working. It does not change the line on the graph so I am assuming the state is not saved. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know why the JS example code is storing and updating the same values using both props and state.  It seems like it should be one or the other.  You can either do away with the props (you would need an initial value in your component) or do away with the state and let it be controlled entirely by the parent.

Comment: It's also weird that the `setOrders` function takes the arguments as an array instead of an object.  They are converting from an object to an array and back to an object. https://github.com/MenesesGHZ/polynomial-regression-js/blob/master/src/components/Main.js

Comment: Can you please help me by writing an answer? I haven't worked in React for a long time and I seem to have forgotten stuff :( @LindaPaiste Good catch for the setOrders btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the value of `order_graph_1` and `order_graph_2` that you get from props but updating the ones that you have in state and not updating the ones in the props.

The code that you are converting updates both the state and the props (by calling `this.props.setOrders`).  But it is totally unnecessary to have these variables in a component state of `RegressionSetup` at all since it can already access and update them through props.

The `setOrders` function which is passed down from [the parent](https://github.com/MenesesGHZ/polynomial-regression-js/blob/master/src/components/Main.js) `Main` component is also a bit silly because both components have a state with properties `order_graph_1` and `order_graph_2` -- so why are we passing them as a tuple to `setOrders`?

In `Main` you can delete the `setOrders` function and instead pass down an arrow function that calls `setState`.

```
<RegressionSetup
  order_graph_1={this.state.order_graph_1}
  order_graph_2={this.state.order_graph_2}
  setOrders={(orders) => this.setState(orders)}
/>
```

`setState` in a class component takes a partial new state and merges it with the current state.  That means the we don't even have to pass *both* orders to `setOrders`. We can call it with just one order and that's fine.

So we can define the props for our `RegressionComponent` like this:

```
export interface OrderGraphs {
  order_graph_1: number;
  order_graph_2: number;
}

interface Props extends OrderGraphs {
  setOrders(graphs: Partial<OrderGraphs>): void;
}
```

There is no reason for it to be a class component, but it also doesn't matter.  `RegressionSetup` does not need to use state, hooks, or lifecycle methods.  It just takes props and returns JSX.

I still prefer to render the two inputs using a function since it's less repetition but obviously you don't have to do that.  We use the variable `property` to get the correct property from props `value={this.props[property]}` and to set the correct key on the object that we pass to `setOrders`: `onChange={(e) => this.props.setOrders({[property]: parseInt(e.target.value, 10)})}`

```
class RegressionSetup extends React.Component<Props> {
  renderInput(property: keyof OrderGraphs, label: string) {
    return (
      <div className="col-6">
        <p className="text-center">{label}</p>
        <div className="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <input
            className="text-center"
            name={property}
            type="number"
            value={this.props[property]}
            onChange={(e) =>
              this.props.setOrders({ [property]: parseInt(e.target.value, 10) })
            }
            min="1"
            max="10"
            step="1"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {this.renderInput("order_graph_1", "Order of first model: ")}
        {this.renderInput("order_graph_2", "Order of second model: ")}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/conversion-to-ts-polynomial-regression-1968y?file=/src/components/RegressionSetup.tsx)

I messed with the other components as well.  I added `Props` and `State` types for everything.  I also used arrow functions to get rid of all the `bind(this)` calls.  There are still a few Typescript errors related to the external packages (chart.js and mathjs).

Answer (score 0):

A React component only rerenders upon state change. You should therefore change the state accordingly to the value of the input field every time the value changes, and then simply load this state value in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

This is causing issue `value={this.props.order_graph_1}` The value here is derived from props instead of state. Ideally it should be populate using some state and onChange should update that state.
Since after every rerender, the props won't change and the input value will still remain the same.

`this.state.order_graph_1` should be the value for input field.